# Yarn install: "Not a git repository" error when fetching packages

Tags: javascript, yarnpkg

**System:** Windows 10 64 bit

I am trying to build a JavaScript project using `yarn install --lock-file` in the repository directory. When yarn tries to fetch the packages, it fails with the following error message:

> Exit code: 128
>   Command: git
>   Arguments: pull
>   Directory: C:\Users\[UserDirectory]\AppData\Local\Yarn\Cache\v2.tmp\9f5ed3b3940e461693021bf6d9a7805d
>   Output:
>   fatal: not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git

I cannot figure out why yarn is trying to use git pull in another directory. Can you explain me what yarn is doing here?

**Edit:**
At first, I guessed it must be an issue with access rights, but running it with elevated access gave the same result. The same goes for `yarn install`, so without the `--frozen-lockfile` flag.

Comment: I guess it is not a git problem? maybe you could remove the git tag then

Comment: @OznOg I was not entirely sure, as I do not completely understand what is happing this point. But I guess you are right to exclude a misbehavior in git?

Comment: well git error is clear, you are atempting to perform a git pull in a directory which is not a git directory (ie, git cannot find its metadata in the .git subdirectory that should be there)

Comment: Yes, true.Removed it

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I was getting the same error in a repo of mine too for any Yarn command.

Removing the *Yarn Cache* fixed Yarn for me: `yarn cache clean` **(recommended)** or

```bash
rm -rf C:\Users\<user>\AppData\Local\Yarn\Cache\v2.tmp\<hash> # the older hacky way
```

Comment: Hey mate, now it's been so long since I asked this question that I even forgot which repo I was using back then. :) Since it seems to work for people, though (judging by the upvotes of your response), I will accept your answer it finally put this question to rest. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Always glad to help yourself and others my dude 

Comment: `yarn cache clean` works like a charm. I would recommend you to put it as a "first" answer and not as a simple edit as this is the recommended way to proceed ;)

Comment: done (; moved to first answer

Answer (score 0):

if someone still can't solve the problem, can try `git init`

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please edit to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.